# Remove a Page from Site Report in Omniture (SiteCatalyst)

Tags: adobe-analytics

Due to a weird reason, I mixed up a name of Report Suite within my site and gave it a wrong Suite's name. The Report Suite has therefore logged in couple of pages that don't belong to it.

Is it possible I can remove the entry of those two pages within Reports in Omniture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is 100% permanent once it hits Adobe Analytics data collection servers. As an alternative, you can apply a filter to exclude those particular items from any important reports:

1. Log in to Adobe Analytics and access the report you would like to exclude the line items from
2. Just below the graph, there is a search filter. Click advanced next to it
3. Select the dropdown 'Does Not Contain', enter a value to exclude. Repeat for all pages you'd like to omit.
4. The resulting report will not have the specified line items included.

Comment: Hi Gigazelle, one small problem. I did as you said but I can't save the results for my report. When I go back to Dashboard, the results again come back to original :(, any help?

Comment: Filters apply to dashboard reportlets as well. Go into the dashboard, click on the reportlet to go into the full report, apply the filter, and there should be a bar at the top asking you to save reportlet changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the comments to Report section, mention those pagenames in the log so that, you can exclude this data.

One more option would be, apply SAINT classification to these pages by giving some value (something like: "WRONG PAGES") so that, you can exclude these pages while analysing the data.

Cheers!